# determine whether a set is algebraic or not

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How can be proved that
$$X=\{( t,\sin t):t\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset \mathbb{R^2}$$
is not an algebraic set? (there isn't a subset $T$ of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ such that X is the zero locus of $T$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume there is such $T$.
Then for each $p \in T$, the polynomial $p(x,0)\in\mathbb R[x]$ has the infinitely many roots $k\pi$, hence must be the zero polynomial. Therefore $p(x,y)=yq(x,y)$ for some polynomial $q$. But then all points $(t,0)$ are in the zero locus of $T$.

Answer (score 4):

The line $y= 0$ intersects the set in infinitely many points, which is not possible for algebraic sets by Bezout theorem.